# regexp, don't match url

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, matching

I have to match words longer than 30 characters, but these words can't be urls.

I tried to do this, but doesn't work fine:

`(?<!ftp)([^\s\t\r\n<>]{30})`

Comment: First of all this will only match words that are exactly 30 characters long

Comment: What characters are allowed in these "long" words you are after? Letters? Digits? Dashes? Dots? Will these words be separated by spaces? tabs? newlines? That, and some example test data would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a few points:

- Your regular expression can match `ftp://example.com` because you are using a lookbehind, which sees nothing before the first f. Use a lookahead instead.
- Also you need to ensure that you match entire words, otherwise you can matching part way into a URL.
- \s includes \t, \n, etc... so the latter is redundant.
- Longer than 30 characters means 31 or more characters, i.e. `{31,}`.

Try this instead:

```
(?<![^\s<>])(?!ftp)([^\s<>]{31,})(?![^\s<>])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
\b(?<!ftp://)\w{30,}\b
```